# Extracting a value from a loop

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a Do loop as follows
`Do [Some Mathematical Operations; FinalResult; ,{t,50}]`
I want to put a condition for `Break` the loop, where I must construct the condition using `FinalResult` of each step and its next step, namely `FinalResult[t]` and `FinalResult[t+1]`. How should I obtain these values?

Comment: perhaps try   [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html) and [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html)?

Comment: my problem isn't writing a condition, but is how to call `FinalResult[t]` and `FinalResult[t+1]` for constructing the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Using `add4` as `FinalResult`

```
add4[x_] := x + 4

Do[a = add4[t];
 If[a == 6 && add4[t + 1] == 7, Break[]], {t, 5}]

a
```

> 6

Note `add4[t + 1]` is only executed if the first part of the condition is satisfied, ie `a == 6`, so it is not too expensive.  If the first condition is likely to be met more often you can use [memoisation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).

```
Clear[add4]
count = 0;

add4[x_] := add4[x] = (count++; x + 4)
Do[a = add4[t];
 If[a <= 6 && add4[t + 1] == 7, Break[]], {t, 5}]

{a, count}
```

> (6, 3}

Comment: You could also use `Throw` and `Catch` to break the loop and return the desired values without having to store them in global variables.

Comment: @Chris Degnen Thanks a lot. In fact, I want to set a convergence test so that if the difference between `FinalResult[t]` and `FinalResult[t+1]` became less than 0.01, the loop breaks.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I will be grateful if you give me a toy example

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using `Catch` and `Throw` to exit loops and returning values obtained inside of the loop:

```
add4[x_] := x + 4

Catch[
 Module[{prev = 0, current},
  Do[
   current = add4[t];
   If[TrueQ[prev/current > 0.9],
    Throw[{current, t}, "result"]
   ];
   prev = current,
   {t, 1, 500}
  ];
  Throw["ERROR; no convergence reached", "result"]
 ],
 "result"
]
```

> > Out[22]= {11, 7}

Note that the use of the tag `"result"` is not strictly necessary, but it's considered good form because it makes it easier to see how the code jumps from one part to another and generally gives you better flow control over your code.

The 2nd `Throw` isn't really necessary either, but without it the result from failing to reach convergence will be `Null`, which doesn't get printed as a result in the notebook (which makes it look like nothing happened).